# error faced when installing SciPy (Details are giving below)

Tags: python, command-line, scipy

I am a new to SciPy and command line. So I followed a tutorial to install scientific python, and below is the link

http://penandpants.com/2013/04/04/install-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/

Yes, I'm  working on Mac OS X, version 10.8.5 Mountain Lion. I have properly installed the latest Xcode, command line and Git. Then I started installing python following the tutorial.

Things seemed to work fine, but I did hit a burden at

```
$ brew install gfortran
```

The following error showed

```
Error: No available formula for gfortran
GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with:
  brew install gcc
```

Thus, I installed gcc. Then as I proceeded to

```
$ brew install scipy --with-openblas
```

The following error appeared

```
error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/exceptions.rb:182:in `dump': undefined local variable or method `f' for #<BuildError:0x10b76f910> (NameError)
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:158
```

As I followed the trouble shooting advices, the following showed

```
aca80164:~ user$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
aca80164:~ user$ brew doctor
```

Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

```
Warning: /usr/local/share/python is not needed in PATH.
Formerly homebrew put Python scripts you installed via `pip` or `pip3`
(or `easy_install`) into that directory above but now it can be removed
from your PATH variable.
Python scripts will now install into /usr/local/bin.
You can delete anything, except 'Extras', from the /usr/local/share/python
(and /usr/local/share/python3) dir and install affected Python packages
anew with `pip install --upgrade`.

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

python
```

From my shallow knowledge, the first warning seemed to be fine, what concerned me are the second and third warning, and I am not sure how to proceed from here. I hope to have some advice. Thank you.

Comment: I'd start with `brew install python`: that `--single-version-externally-managed` error tends to show up on old Python/setuptools distributions, and Homebrew is also complaining about the Python you're using.